# Assignation does't take effect inside two-dimension array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array full of credentials following this pattern:

```
Array (
    [0] : Array (
        "login" => "toto"
        "passwd" => "mdpsecrethashe"
    )
    [1] : Array (
        "login" => "titi"
        "passwd" => "supermdp"
    )
    [2] : Array (
        [...]
    )
    [...]
)
```

I want to get the desired credentials thanks to the login and change the password. Here is my attempt:

```
function getListWithModifiedPassword($credentials_list, $wanted_login, $new_password){
    echo(print_r($credentials_list, TRUE));
    foreach ($credentials_list as $credentials)
        if ($credentials['login'] === $wanted_login)
            $credentials['passwd'] = hash('whirlpool', $new_password);
    echo(print_r($credentials_list, TRUE));
    return $credentials_list;
}
```

Assignation on line 5 doesn't want to work whatever the value (no change between the two `echo(print_r($credentials_list, TRUE));`, even though the condition on line 4 is true (tested: if I replace line 5 with `echo "Hello world\n";` it works).

What is happenning in here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP's foreach loop you are working with copy of the array. So your assignation to `$credentials['passwd']` does not take effect for `$credentials_list`.

You have 2 options:

1. pass to the foreach reference value (notice `&` before $credentials in foreach bracket and also `unset` function which stops accidental assignation to the variable after foreach - [see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)):

```
foreach($credentials_list as &$credentials) {
    if ($credentials['login'] === $wanted_login)
            $credentials['passwd'] = hash('whirlpool', $new_password);
}
unset($credentials);
```

2. assign value directly into original array:

```
foreach($credentials_list as $key => $credentials) {
    if ($credentials['login'] === $wanted_login)
        $credentials_list[$key]['passwd'] = hash('whirlpool', $new_password);
}
```

Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 0):

instead write this to print

```
var_dump($credentials_list);
```

if you are returning the value then no need to print_r or echo